# Storing API credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

How does one store API credentials in a way that they cannot be hacked? For example, AWS keys, or Google cloud keys?

In production use (say Heroku or EC2 instance), if you have say a Github repository, then this can easily get hacked. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You don't ever commit credentials like that to code. In your Heroku example you would [set them as config variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) and then your code would pull the values from the environment when needed.

In AWS you could [do something similar](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html), or you could use the AWS KMS service or the [AWS SSM Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html). Also, on AWS when you are accessing other AWS services you would use the IAM Roles assigned to your resources instead of using credentials directly.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you don't.

Best practice on AWS is to use IAM Instance (or Task) Roles assigned to your EC2 (or ECS) instances.  From the documentation:

> We designed IAM roles so that your applications can securely make API requests from your instances, without requiring you to manage the security credentials that the applications use. Instead of creating and distributing your AWS credentials, you can delegate permission to make API requests using IAM roles.

You can read more about how IAM Roles work in the *IAM Roles for Amazon EC2* section of the AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html